# Frobenius norm of $||AA^+ - I||_F = ? $

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, svd, pseudoinverse

I need to find a value for the following norm $||AA^+ - I||_F$, where:

- $A^+$ is the Moore–Penrose Inverse matrix
- $||A||_F = \sqrt{Tr(AA^T)}$
- A have $n \times m$ dimension and have rank $r$

I have try to do the SVD decomposition of the matrix $AA^+ - I$, but I couldn't go further because I don't know how the decomposition in SVD of $A$ have a relation with $A^+$.

Comment: Check out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Singular_value_decomposition_(SVD)) about SVD for $A^+$.

Comment: But you know how can I reach that formula for $A^+$?

Comment: For unitary $B$ [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Products) $(AB)^+=B^+A^+$ and $(BA)^+=A^+B^+$. Hence, $A^+=(U\Sigma V^*)^+=...$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781096/matrix-multiplied-by-its-pseudo-inverse-doesnt-give-the-identity-matrix-why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{R}$.

$AA^+$ is a symmetric matrix, the eigenvalues of which, being $1$ ($r\;\times$) and $0$ ($n-r\;\times$).

Then $AA^+-I_n$ is orthogonally similar to $D=diag(0_r,-I_{n-r})$.

Finally $||AA^+-I_n||_F=||D||_F=\sqrt{n-r}$.

Comment: isn't $\sqrt{r-n}$ because of minus sign?

Comment: No. One has a root of sum of squares.