# Showing properties of Moore–Penrose matrix using the SVD decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, pseudoinverse

> Using the Singular Value Decomposition, show:
>
> 1. $\operatorname{Rank}(A)=\operatorname{Rank}(AA^*)=\operatorname{Rank}(A^*A)$.
> 2. $A^{+}=A^*(AA^*)^{-1}$.
> 3. $\operatorname{null}(A^{+})=\operatorname{null}(A^*)$.
>
> where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose matrix, and $A^*$ is the transpose conjugate matrix.

---

There are many identities on the Moore-Penrose matrix, on the following Wikipedia page, with no proofs.

Moore-penrose matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse.

Part 1 can be shown with the rank-theorem since $\operatorname{null}(A)=\operatorname{null}(AA^*)$ thus $\dim(\operatorname{null}(A))=\dim(\operatorname{null}(A^*))$ which is the same as,
$\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(AA^*)$. And if we use SVD decomposition it will give us the same result:

$A=VDU^*$ where $V$ and $U$ are orthogonal matrix, and $D=diag{\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_n}$.
Where $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ are the singular values of $A$.
It is easy to see that
$Rank(A)=Rank(D)$.
Then,

$A^*=UD^*V^*$.

$AA^*=V(DD^*)V^*$

$A^*A=U(D^*D)U^*$

So, we get the SVD of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$.

It is obvious that $rank(DD^*)=rank(D^*D)=rank(D)$.
Thus,
$rank(AA^*)=rank(A^*A)=rank(A)$

But I did not manage to use the SVD to show part 2 and part 3 in  the properties above.
Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3781776/339790

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo de Azevedo i edited my   solution for the 1st part above, however the link did not much help me to show the other parts, since I need to prove the identity from the beginning not as a fact..can you help..

Comment: Write everything in terms of block matrices. Pay attention to the sizes of the blocks.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo I looked at the the link and understood what you meant, however I am not getting it!  (Can you also look ate the part 1 I solved).

Comment: Your approach is too foreign to me and I don't have the time at the moment to invest in it. Again, give the block matrix approach a try. Google "4 fundamental subspaces".